# background image shifts around in CSS

Tags: css

i have an image set as the background of my header. When I resize my window in chrome the image is moved around (shifts around different areas of the image)

below is my css:

```
#home::before { /* issue that the image moves as the window is resized */
    content: "";
    background: url('../images/beach.JPG') no-repeat 0 500px;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;X
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 900px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: ;
  }
```

Comment: Could you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: You need to fix errors first: 1. remove X from `bottom: 0;X` line 2. set value for `opacity: ;` or remove the property

Comment: Sorry not sure where that X came from it's not in the code and the opacity was set. Same issue.